# Cube Agree GTC - Tri-Bars

Tags: road-bike, compatibility, aerodynamics, triathlon

I have a Cube Agree GTC (2012), and I would like to buy some tri-bars for it. I've [read](http://m.triradar.com/gear/cube-agree-gtc-road-bike-review/) that this model (
Although, on second thoughts, maybe this is a newer model...) has compatibility issues with clip on tri-bars so I was hoping that someone has already solved this problem, if one exists (I've never bought or clipped on tri-bars before)

Has anyone satisfactorily purchased tri-bars for this model? Any recommendations?

Comment: This question is too specific for the stack exchange format, and as it is a shopping question, it is likely to be closed. My suggestion for this is to go to your local bike shop and get them to recommend you some tri-bars for the bike. Note that you will need to redo your bike fit when you have tri bars installed, since your riding position will change significantly.

Comment: What do you mean "it does not lend itself well"? Are you referring to a compatibility issue? A comfort issue? A fit issue? Aerodynamics? Something else entirely?

Comment: I've added a link to that 'does not lend itself...' article. Apparently, they don't fit well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I got a reply from Cube about this. They basically told me to get a new drop bar.. They just want to cover themselves in terms of the warranty I suppose, so fair enough.

I took the risk and bought [these](https://www.cyclesuperstore.ie/shop/pc/viewPrd.asp?idproduct=47228). They worked like a charm. Maybe (just maybe) I had to clip them on closer together than I, initially, would have liked. But, I did my first Olympic triathlon at the weekend with them, they were great.

I say go for it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the review, it simply sounds like the cross-section of the bar is different than a usual bar. So, if you want to attach tri-bars to the bike, you may need to get a new drop bar (which has the usual circular cross-section), and then attach the tri bars to that bar.

Of course, if the bike works well with the new drop bar and tri bars are all highly a function of you and the particular bike, which we can't really determine over the internet - You'll probably just have to try it or get advice from your LBS on it, since they can probably fit you in a tri-position.